# SQL Server - No hay ningun proceso de canalizacion en el otro extremo

Tags: sql, python-3.x

Al abrir SQL Server con autenticacion de windows me salta ese error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En SQL Server Configuration Manager tengo todo habilitado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me sucede cuando inicio Python, es decir, puedo leer la base de datos desde Python pero mientras tanto no puedo conectarme desde Management Studio

Cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: Prueba con los que dicen aqui (https://support.microsoft.com/es-co/help/919710/error-message-when-you-try-to-connect-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-200)  y ¿Qué modo de autenticación usas? ¿Windows o mixta (con login y password)? Si es mixta, ¿está habilitada la autenticación mixta?

Comment: Autenticacion con windows

Comment: Ya probaste las soluciones del la url que puse en el primer comentario ?

Comment: Puedes verificar, solo para no obviar, que tu windows firewall no esté activado o si lo está, verificar que el puerto 1433 esté abierto?